# Why won`t this simple function output anything if I don`t use a break statement?

Tags: java

Function here is , implemented to find the largest number in an array .. if I don't put a break statement after while , it won't print out anything . I need someone to explain me how this code works .
What I was thinking is that ,

1- we go into first loop , and then the second loop..
2- we have the first and second elements compared in the while loop .
3- if condition is true , int largest is set to the large value..
4- and then we go back to the outer for loop again .

Isn't this true ? aren't we going back to the outer for loop after while statement is issued once ? If I don't put a break , while condition is true , the program won't come out of the loop , is that so ?

I`m testing the code in main , by calling this function and passing in an integer array . I forgot to mention this before . Sorry .

Thank you .

```
public int returnMax(int[] nums) {
    int largest = 0;
    for (int i = 0; i < nums.length; i++) {
        for (int j = 1; j < nums.length; j++) {
            while (nums[j] > nums[i]) {
                largest = nums[j];
                break;
                
            }

        }
    }
    return largest;

}
```

Comment: The only print statement in that code is commented out, So nothing there should print anything with or without the break.

Comment: Sorry , my bad that I did not mention I`m testing the function in main . When I test this function with break statement , it works fine , prints out the largest int in an int array . If I do not put a break statement and test the function , it won`t print out anything .

Comment: Better question: why are you using two loops in the first place? You just need one loop to iterate over all elements. Simply test each element against *current* `max` and if it is greater assign it to `max`. Something like `int max = -1; for (int currentNumber : nums) if (currentNumber>max) max = currentNumber;`.

Comment: Right , that`s way more efficient , but sadly , this was the first answer came into my mind during a quick junior java test .. so I wanted to ask about this solution . Thank you for the information though !

Comment: It's not only way more efficient, it's correct.  Consider what your function does with input `[3, 2, 1]`.  It returns `2`, do you know why?

Answer (score 3):

if `nums[j]` is larger than `nums[i]` it goes into your while loop.
In your while loop you *never* change any variable except for `largest`. Largest is never used except for returning a value. This causes an infinite loop because the next iteration your while expression is the still the same.

Comment: Thank you man ! That`s a nice explanation of what has been going on there .. makes sense .

Answer (score 1):

The program can't leave the while statement, because the condition is never changes and is always true (once it's true). You should replace the `while` with an `if`.

```
if (nums[j] > nums[i]) {
    largest = nums[j];
    System.out.println(largest);
}
```

Also you out commented `System.out.println(largest);`, so it will never be called

Comment: Oh I see now .. thank you very much ! I tried it out and actually , it works and makes sense .

Comment: @begumsakin with that change, it works... unless the largest number is at index 0 in the array. Because `j` goes from 1 to n and largest can only ever be set to `nums[j]` for some `j`, `largest` can never be set to `nums[0]`. If that position holds the largest number, you'll get the wrong answer. Try it with the example from asm's comment on the question.

Answer (score 1):

The first time your code gets to the while loop, j = 1 and i = 0, which means that j is greater than i. These numbers don't change inside this loop. Thus, the loop will never end and the code won't proceed.

You don't need 3 loops for this simple operation. Try the below.

```
public static int returnMax(int[] nums) {
        int largest = nums[0];
        for (int i = 1; i < nums.length; i++) {
            if (largest < nums[i]) {
                largest = nums[i];
            }
        }
        return largest;
    }
```

Kind Regards